# Seperating Axis Theorom For Collision Detection issues

Tags: java, collision-detection, separating-axis-theorem

I have been attempting to use the SAT test to determine whether two of my convex meshes are colliding, however I've encountered are rather strange issue. The algorithm does determine whether the objects are colliding but sometimes it seems to almost ignore orientation of one of the objects.
[image: Cube "floating" due to collision issue]

I am for the record, performing collisions on the polygon itself however it appears as if i am performing collision detection of the bounding box of the object. Strangely if i change the orientation of the platform that the cube is sitting on, the cube will collide with the surface of the platform in a similar way, with it appearing to collide the cube's bounding box with the platform's surface.

Even more strangely if i force the cube to collide with the platform then it functions correctly:
[image: Forced collision with platform]

Here's the code I've implemented, i'm aware there's a couple inefficiencies in the code but i'm just trying to get it running properly first:

```
public CollisionData convexCollisions(Mesh a, Mesh b){
    CollisionData data = new CollisionData();
    data.penetration_depth=Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double s1_min, s2_min, s1_max, s2_max;

    //TEST OBJECTS AGAINST THE POTENTIAL AXIS FROM MESH A

    //rotation matrix for the normals
    double[][] rot_mat=Matrix.rotationYawPitchRoll(a.rotation.x, a.rotation.y, a.rotation.z);

    for(int i=0; i<a.faces.size(); i++){

        //the normals are stored in model space so i have to convert them to world space by rotating them according to the meshes orientation
        Vector3 normal = Matrix.vectorMatrixMultiply(a.faces.get(i).normal, rot_mat).normalize();

        double[] a_test=SATtest(normal, a.vertices);
        s1_min=a_test[0];
        s1_max=a_test[1];
        double[] b_test=SATtest(normal, b.vertices);
        s2_min=b_test[0];
        s2_max=b_test[1];

        double overlap=getOverlap(s1_min, s1_max, s2_min, s2_max);

        //if the overlap is negative, there is no collision so early out
        if(overlap<0){
            return null;
        }else {
            if(overlap<data.penetration_depth) {
                data.penetration_depth=overlap;
                data.normal=normal;
            }
        }
    }

    //TEST OBJECTS AGAINST POTENTIAL AXIS FROM MESH B

    rot_mat=Matrix.rotationYawPitchRoll(b.rotation.x, b.rotation.y, b.rotation.z);

    for(int i=0; i<b.faces.size(); i++){
        Vector3 normal = Matrix.vectorMatrixMultiply(b.faces.get(i).normal, rot_mat).normalize();

        //double s1_min, s2_min, s1_max, s2_max;
        double[] a_test=SATtest(normal, a.vertices);
        s1_min=a_test[0];
        s1_max=a_test[1];
        double[] b_test=SATtest(normal, b.vertices);
        s2_min=b_test[0];
        s2_max=b_test[1];

        double overlap=getOverlap(s1_min, s1_max, s2_min, s2_max);

        //if the overlap is negative, there is no collision so early out
        if(overlap<0){
            return null;
        }else {
            if(overlap<data.penetration_depth) {
                data.penetration_depth=overlap;
                data.normal=normal;
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}

public double[] SATtest(Vector3 axis, Vertex[] points){
    double minAlong = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double maxAlong = Double.MIN_VALUE;

    for(int i=0; i<points.length; i++){
        double dotAlongAxis = points[i].world_coordinates.dot(axis);
        minAlong=(dotAlongAxis<minAlong)?dotAlongAxis:minAlong;
        maxAlong=(dotAlongAxis>maxAlong)?dotAlongAxis:maxAlong; 
    }

    return new double[]{minAlong, maxAlong};
}

public double getOverlap(double s1_min, double s1_max, double s2_min, double s2_max){
    return Math.min(s1_max, s2_max)-Math.max(s1_min, s2_min);
}
```

So it is safe to say that i am thoroughly confused, if anyone has any suggestions on what the issue could be i'd appreciate it.

Comment: Debug visually, In the case where they are not intersecting, what is the separating axis, and what does the separating plane look like?

Comment: Your code makes logical sense to me, except the SATtest() method, I'm not 100% sure how that's supposed to work... I thought you were supposed to project all vertices onto the plane (defined by the axis (polygon normal)). Then check if there are overlaps between the two projections.

Comment: The SATtest method projects the points onto a plane that corresponds to the normal, and returns the extremities of the projection (minAlong and maxAlong) and then the convexCollisions method determines whether the extremities if the two meshes overlap on that axis